Forking Pancakeswap V2 to BSC
hardhat.config
require('@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers');
require('dotenv').config();

const { BSC_API_URL, MNEMONIC } = process.env;

module.exports = {
  solidity: "0.5.16",
  networks: {
    bsc: {
      url: BSC_API_URL,
      accounts: {
        mnemonic: MNEMONIC,
      },
    },
    hardhat: {
      forking: {
        url: BSC_API_URL,
      },
    },
  },
};

scripts/deploy.js
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
    const [deployer] = await ethers.getSigners();

    const PancakeFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory('PancakeFactory');
    const factory = await PancakeFactory.deploy(deployer.address);
    await factory.deployed();
    console.log('PancakeFactory deployed to:', factory.address);

    const PancakePair = await ethers.getContractFactory('PancakePair');
    const pair = await PancakePair.deploy();
    await pair.deployed();
    console.log('PancakePair deployed to:', pair.address);

    console.log(`PancakeFactory Address: ${factory.address}`);
    console.log(`PancakePair Address: ${pair.address}`);
}

main()
    .then(() => process.exit(0))
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(1);
    });


After running npx hardhat compile i am getting error
PS D:\task\pancake-swap-core\scripts> npx hardhat compile
Error HH8: There's one or more errors in your config file:

Invalid value {"forking":{}} for HardhatConfig.networks.hardhat - Expected a value of type HardhatNetworkConfig.
Invalid value undefined for HardhatConfig.networks.bsc.url - Expected a value of type string.
Invalid value {} for HardhatConfig.networks.bsc - Expected a value of type HttpNetworkHDAccountsConfig.

To learn more about Hardhat's configuration, please go to https://hardhat.org/config/
How do i sucessfully fork pancake swap v2 to bsc??

The issue is that it is unable to read the variables from .env file.
Have you created a .env file in the root directory of the Hardhat project?
In the .env file, you'll need to add a rpc url for bsc-test from here
You'll also need a account mnemonic that you can get from a wallet like Metamask. Here's the link to getting your secret-phrase. I have added a sample mnemonic phrase for you.
BSC_API_URL=https://data-seed-prebsc-1-s1.binance.org:8545/
MNEMONIC=carpet cat flower chair foot river make image amazing three say shoe

After adding the values to the variables in your .env file, try compiling the contracts again. It should work.
